# SQL model solution for money transactions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, merkle-tree

I am creating an application that users could deposit money on their account and trasfer to other users. I am wondering if Markle Tree is the ideal solution for SQL transaction for money transfer. I've read [this article](https://medium.com/@benjaminsky/blockchain-by-example-in-sql-server-8376b410128), and came with the idea of implementing this kind of "security" in my app for preventing someone to change some values.

So, how could be the best solution to implement on my database model, does anyone could help me? For now, my database look like this:

[image]

The main idea is to create a transaction since there is a payment, and the transaction only occour if the sum of the value of all transactions of the user is equal to the amount in his account. Is that a good way, or could be better?

Comment: *since there is a payment, and the transaction only occour if the sum of the value of all transactions of the user is equal to the amount in his account.* ??? the account balance may be positive or zero, it cannot be negative onlt.

Comment: "help me" is not an on-topic question. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) This is too vague & general. [ask] [help] PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Every transaction must have a state - it is either a `draft` or `applied`. When you try to `apply` a transaction - an SQL trigger should ensure that the new balance of the sending account does not become negative (and abort the transaction otherwise). The trigger can either compute the balance each time - or cache it inside the corresponding account (and update the value after every successful transaction).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve. I understand that you want to sell something on the internet and you are creating a database for it. If you want to sell a subscription, the more important issue is the validity of the purchased service (date from-to). Take a look at the model below.

Database model for transaction-subscription:
[image: database model for transaction-subscription]